# How can I provide additional type information to an existing type?

Tags: typescript, vue-router

How can I add type information for **params** in this example?

```
router.beforeEach((to, _from, next) => {
  console.log(to.params.id);
  next();
});
```

The problem is that *TypeScript* does not know that **params** will always have an **id** that consists of a `String`.

What I have tried so far is to intersect the current type, which is `RouteLocationNormalized`, with my own type:

```
type CustomType = RouteLocationNormalized & { params: { id: string } };

router.beforeEach((to: CustomType, _from, next) => {
  console.log(to.params.id);
  next();
});
```

However, this did not work, and instead resulted in an error that I could not decipher:

> Argument of type '(this: undefined, to: CustomType, _from:
> RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) => void' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationGuardWithThis'.
> Types of parameters 'to' and 'to' are incompatible.
> Type 'RouteLocationNormalized' is not assignable to type 'CustomType'.
> Type 'RouteLocationNormalized' is not assignable to type '{ params: { id: string; }; }'.
> Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
> Property 'id' is missing in type 'RouteParams' but required in type '{ id: string; }'.ts(2345)

I would appreciate any help that informs *TypeScript* about **id**, so that it is clear that the property is available.

**Update:**

I have modified my custom type:

```
type CustomType = RouteLocationNormalized & {
  params: RouteParams & { [id: string]: string | string[] };
};
```

This pretty much works as intended, but for some reason I cannot have **id** be just a `String`. It has to be either a `String` or a `String[]`, which is not exactly correct.

*See line 35 in https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/src/types/index.ts*

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this problem by implementing an interface that extends `RouteLocationNormalized`. The interface contains **params** and maintains the `RouteParams` type, which then intersects the new object:

```
interface CustomInterface extends RouteLocationNormalized {
  params: RouteParams & { id?: string };
}

router.beforeEach((to: CustomInterface, _from, next) => {
  console.log(to.params.id);
  next();
});
```